# On commutation relations in QFT

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-field-theory, commutator, qft-in-curved-spacetime

I am self learning “Quantum fields in curved space” and I am stuck at trying to show the commutation relations for the free real scalar field. I know that the usual way to show is to invoke the Fourier transform and substitute in the equal time commutation relations to prove. However, Birrell & Davies' Eq (2.17) wrote the operator $\phi$ as a discrete sum of the modes of the field rather than an integral in the continuum limit. As such, how should I show the commutation relations now that I have to work with series instead of integrals?

Comment: Which book? Which page?

Comment: The book is “ Quantum fields in curved space” and the relevant chapter is chapter 2. I believe I’m using the second edition so it should be page 13, Eq (2.17).

Comment: Author of said book? Birrell and Davies?

Comment: Yes, Birrell and Davies.

Comment: The equation you cite is$$\phi(t,\,x)=\sum_{\mathrm{k}}[a_\mathrm{k}u_\mathrm{k}(t,\,\mathrm{x})+a^\dagger_\mathrm{k}u^\ast_\mathrm{k}(t,\,\mathrm{x})],$$which is preceded by $\pi=\partial_t\phi$ and followed immediately by$$[a_\mathrm{k},\,a_{\mathrm{k}^\prime}]=0,\,[a_\mathrm{k},\,a^\dagger_{\mathrm{k}^\prime}]=\delta_{\mathrm{k}\mathrm{k}^\prime}.$$Please edit in your attempt to use this to compute the equal-time commutator $[\phi(t,\,\mathrm{x}),\,\pi(t,\,\mathrm{y})]$ so we can pinpoint your confusion.